# NHibertate query by mapped Dictionary

Tags: nhibernate, dictionary, hql, queryover

Could you help me with nhibernate query.
There is next object with mapping:

```
public ObjectkState
{
public long Id {get;set;}
public IDictionary<string,string> Context {get;set;}
public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

Object mapping

```
public ObjectStateMap(): ClassMappublic ObjectStateMap()
{
 Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity();
 Map(x => x.Name);
 HasMany(x => x.Context).Table("ContextItems").KeyColumn("TaskId")
 .Cascade.All()
 .AsMap("ItemKey").Element("ItemValue", c => c.Type());
}
```

Please help me to make query like: Find all ObjectStates where Name = "New" and Context contains key "TaskId" and value "3". Гnfortunately I don't find any examples how to find against mapped IDictionary.

Comment: Maybe you should consider using a list of wrapper objects instead of the Dictionary?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use Linq to NHibernate. You can also use HQL.

Perhaps something like this:

```
   session.Query<ObjectStateMap>()
            .Where(x => x.Name == "New")
            .Where(x => x.Context.ContainsKey("SubscriptionTypeID"))
            .ToList();
```

I know i'm missing the Value restriction, but that's easy enough to add in.

I am struggling to find this functionality in QueryOver though.